# Чтение SQL таблицы через Pandas

Tags: python, mysql, pandas, dataframe, numpy

Есть SQL таблица, которая читается через Pandas.

Возможно ли изменить формат вывода даты и времени на `'2019-10-10 10:00:00'` в одном столбце `datetime` и сделать данный столбец индексом?

```
     date     time    open    high    low     close
0  20191010  100000  131030  131450  131030  131130
1  20191010  103000  131120  131120  130560  130770
2  20191010  110000  130780  131250  130630  131180
3  20191010  113000  131190  131230  130900  130920
4  20191010  120000  130920  131110  130740  130790
5  20191010  123000  130790  131170  130700  131100

connection = pymysql.connect(host='localhost', user='root', passwd='******', db='quotes')
stocks = pd.io.sql.read_sql("SELECT * FROM 30min", connection)
connection.close()
```

Comment: +1 к карме за хорошо оформленный вопрос, включающий пример данных)

Comment: спасибо сильно выручили!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Решение при помощи Pandas:

Исходный DataFrame:

```
In [5]: df
Out[5]:
       date    time    open    high     low   close
0  20191010  100000  131030  131450  131030  131130
1  20191010  103000  131120  131120  130560  130770
2  20191010  110000  130780  131250  130630  131180
3  20191010  113000  131190  131230  130900  130920
4  20191010  120000  130920  131110  130740  130790
5  20191010  123000  130790  131170  130700  131100
```

Решение:

```
In [6]: df = df.set_index(pd.to_datetime(df.pop("date").astype(str) 
                                         + " " 
                                         + df.pop("time").astype(str)))
```

Результат:

```
In [7]: df
Out[7]:
                       open    high     low   close
2019-10-10 10:00:00  131030  131450  131030  131130
2019-10-10 10:30:00  131120  131120  130560  130770
2019-10-10 11:00:00  130780  131250  130630  131180
2019-10-10 11:30:00  131190  131230  130900  130920
2019-10-10 12:00:00  130920  131110  130740  130790
2019-10-10 12:30:00  130790  131170  130700  131100
```

---

такое же преобразование можно сделать и на стороне MySQL DB:

```
select
    str_to_date(concat(cast(date as char(8)), cast(time as char(6))), '%Y%m%d%h%i%s') as dt,
    open,
    high,
    low,
    close
from 30min;
```